# Problem in solving a theorem in linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

**The question is** :

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a n-dimensional real vector space $V$ such that $T$ is diagonalizable. Then there exists an orthonormal basis for $V$ in which the matrix representation of $T$ is upper triangular.

How can I proceed?Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can I use Schur's theorem?

Comment: What does orthonormal mean when all you have is an $n$-dimensional real vector space?

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean by it.

Comment: Sorry I cant comment for next few hours.It's my sleeping time.